# How to maximize q and pi?

Tags: optimization, nash-equilibrium

I am desperate about some functions I would like to understand. I hope someone can help me to understand.

Lets suppose we have a demand-function like:

$$ D_i=\ \ 1/3+\ \ (2q_i-\ \sum_{j\neq i}\ q_j)/(2t) $$

And the corresponding profit function looks like:

$$
\pi_i=(p-c\ast q_i\ )\ast D_i.
$$

In order to calculate quality and profit level in the Nash equilibrium, it is stated that the qualities are derived by the first order condition. The results are:

$$
q_i^*\ \ =\ \ p/c\ \ -\ \ t/3
$$

$$
\pi_i^*=ct/9
$$

I tried to derive the profit function by p and q, but I couldn't  make it to the stated results.

May the solution be quite straightforward, I can't think about it and would appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks in advance
KR

EDIT: For my understanding, the first order condition is the first derivative of the profit function that needs to set zero, what means the slope is zero. For identification, if its a minimum or maximum one need to evaluate the second derivative. I failed at the first derivative due to the summation sign. I know how to interpret it, but I don't know how to derive it. Following this, all I got is:

$$(d\pi)/dq = -c*(dD_i/dq)$$

EDIT: My recent solutions:

$$((d\pi)/(dq)) = (p-c*q)*(1/t)+(1/3+((2q-j)/(2t))*(-c)$$

$$ 0 \overset{!}{=} (p-c*q)*(1/t)+(1/3+((2q-j)/(2t))*(-c) $$

$$ q = (-3ct^2 + 6c-2t)/(6p-6ct^2) $$

Comment: Can you show what you tried to get an answer, and what result you got?

Comment: Sure! In fact that the first order condition is represented by the first derivative, I tried to derive the profit function by q. The problem is, that I don't know what to do with the summation sign. I know that its per definition just the sum of q_j + ... + q_J, excluding q_i. But what I don't know is, how this looks and how it gets derived. So my understanding ended with $$(d\pi/dq)=-c*D

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you should be differentiating $\pi_i$ with respect to $q_i$, i.e. find $\frac{\partial \pi_i}{\partial q_i}$, which means that all of the $q_j$ where $j \neq i$ will be treated as constant.

Second, your derivative is not quite right - remember that $(uv)' = uv' + u'v$, so in this case $\frac{\partial \pi_i}{\partial q_i} = (p - c q_i)\frac{\partial D_i}{\partial q_i} + D_i \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}(p - c q_i)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added the derivative to the question (it doesn't get well formatted in the comment section). To get to the equilibrium, I tried to solve this equilibrium for q (added also to the question). But this solution is far away from the correct solution, so I still don't know were I made a mistake. Is it still the wrong derivative or is the whole approach wrong? In my understanding, the q* comes from solving the first derivative of the profit function by q. Then insert q* in the original profit function which yields to p*. I would very happy if you could comment again.